# Install gcc for MIPS MUSL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gcc

I don't have the file: ld-musl-mips-sf.so which is required by a MIPS binary which I need to execute

I have already installed: gcc-mips-linux-gnu on my machine. How do I install the "musl" version of gcc-mips on Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: Odds are, you'll have to build it from source, but I hope I'm wrong